# Where can I define Conditional compilation constants for Delphi Prism?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, delphi, oxygene

I've just ported a Web service from Delphi.NET 2006 to Delphi Prism 2009 (running in the Visual Studio 2008 IDE).  But I can't find where I'm supposed to set (or unset) the conditional compilation constants!

Am I blind, has this option been left out, or is it just not supported in VS?

[edit: thanks to Mohammed Nasman for the link] MSDN tells me to set them using the Project Designer.  First, it took me a while to figure out that the Project menu is only visible when the Solution is selected (and not the web service project).  Then, there's still no way to set conditional compilation constants in the Project Designer!

I just can't find a way to get to the [Project Options](http://prismwiki.codegear.com/en/Project_Options) in an ASP.NET project...  Is it really not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delphi Prism uses VS [How to: Declare Conditional Compilation Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dxx7dta(VS.80).aspx)

And for Asp.net [Conditional Compilation Constants and ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/16/conditional-compilation-constants-and-asp.net.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you right click on a project node (any project, not just Delphi Prism) in the solution explorer and then click on the Properties option in the context menu the project options tab-book should appear in the text editor pane. Click on the build tab, it should be the third tab down on the left hand side.  The first text-box that appears on that page should be labelled "Conditional Compilation Symbols". It should already contain the symbols: "DEBUG;TRACE".  You can add your own symbols there.

You can also get to the project properties tab-book by selecting the project node in the solution explorer and then clicking on the top-left hand toolbar button in solution explorer window.